# How to discover the BSSID that your WLAN is connected to using NativeWifi API in C#

Tags: c#, wifi, wifimanager, bssid

A WLAN can have more than one BSSID. I need to discovery which BSSID I am connected with.

In the NativeWIFI API using the struct ***WlanAvailableNetwork*** I can discover the WLAN that I am connected to, but it didn't tell me which is the connected BSSID.

In the Struct WlanBssEntry I can get all the BSSID of any WLAN, but i also can't discover which one I am connected.

All that I need is the MAC addrees of the WLAN I am connected with. That's why I want to discover which BSSID I am connected with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already discovered it...
I will post here my solution in case anyone needs it in the future...

```
using NativeWifi;
public  void GetLog(int Count)
        {
            string Conectividade = "Disc";//Initi variable Conectividade as Disconnected
            string RRate = "0";//Initi variable RRate as 0
            string TRate = "0";//Initi variable TRate as 0

            WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
            foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)// Get the WLANs available
            {
                Wlan.WlanAssociationAttributes conAttributes = wlanIface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes;//Get the Attributes of current connection 
                string ConnectedSSID = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(conAttributes.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString();//Save the SSID of WLAN connected with
                string ReceivedRate = conAttributes.rxRate.ToString();//Save the receipted rate of the connected WLAN
                string TransmitededRate = conAttributes.txRate.ToString();//Save the transmitted rate of the connected WLAN    
                byte[] ConnectedMacAddr = conAttributes.dot11Bssid;//MAC of the BSSID in which the WLAN is connected with
                string ConMac = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < ConnectedMacAddr.Length;                    {
                    ConMac += ConnectedMacAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();//ConMac sera o MAC da BSSID conectada
                }

                Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();//Vector with the BSS available
                Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] wlanAvailableNetwork = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);//Vector with the WLANS available

                WriteLog("\"ID" + listSeparatorQuotes + "DateTime" + listSeparatorQuotes + "SSID" + listSeparatorQuotes + "MAC" + listSeparatorQuotes + "Type" + listSeparatorQuotes + "Auth" + listSeparatorQuotes + "Cipher" + listSeparatorQuotes + "Connection" + listSeparatorQuotes + "RecivRate" + listSeparatorQuotes + "TransmiRate" + listSeparatorQuotes + "SignalQuality" + listSeparatorQuotes + "NumberOfBSSIDS\"", path, "WLANs" + StartDay + StartHour + ".csv");

                foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork AVnetwork in wlanAvailableNetwork)
                {
                    string SSIDatual = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(AVnetwork.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString();//Actual SSID
                    if(SSIDatual.Equals(ConnectedSSID))
                    {
                        Conectividade = "Con";
                        RRate = ReceivedRate;
                        TRate = TransmitededRate;
                    }
                    //___________________________ wlanAvailableNetwork ___________________________
                    WriteLog(Count.ToString() + listSeparator + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + listSeparator + SSIDatual + listSeparator + ConMac + listSeparator +  AVnetwork.dot11BssType + listSeparator + AVnetwork.dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm + listSeparator + AVnetwork.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm + listSeparator + Conectividade + listSeparator + RRate + listSeparator + TRate + listSeparator + AVnetwork.wlanSignalQuality + listSeparator + AVnetwork.numberOfBssids + "\"", path, "WLANs" + StartDay + StartHour + ".csv");//Its a function that's writes a log in the selected path...case you need this function send me a message!
                    //_________________________ End wlanAvailableNetwork _________________________
                    Conectividade = "Disc";//Reinitialize the value of Conectividade                        RRate = "0";//Reinitialize the value of RRate
                    TRate = "0";//Reinitialize the value of TRate
                }
                foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)// Get all existent BSSIDs
                {
                    int rss = network.rssi;
                    byte[] macAddr = network.dot11Bssid;
                    string tMac = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        tMac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();
                    }

                    //___________________________ wlanBSSEntries __________________________
                    WriteLog(Count.ToString() + listSeparator + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss") + listSeparator + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString() + listSeparator + network.dot11BssType + listSeparator + network.chCenterFrequency + listSeparator + network.linkQuality + listSeparator + rss.ToString() + listSeparator + tMac, path, "BSSIDs" + StartDay + StartHour + ".csv");
                    //_________________________ End wlanBSSEntries _________________________



                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

OBS: I'm writing the LOG as a .csv file, and I'm using culture to get the items separator, this way it will work in any place and culture... for example in Brazil and German the item's separator is a ";", but in USA the separator is a ",". It will adapt for any situation...

Here is the code to get the culture and the separation...

```
using System.Globalization;
private static string listSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator; 
private static string listSeparatorQuotes = "\"" + listSeparator + "\"";
```